# Get values from Hash

Tags: ruby

I have value response_data which stores this data:

```
{"response_data"=>
  {"transaction_type"=>"void",
   "status"=>"error",
   "unique_id"=>"ec8b1e786efe64f667ad19ff1b39fb92",
   "transaction_id"=>"kcyplptlpk966yifmuct6jj0od",
   "code"=>"410",
   "technical_message"=>"no approved reference transaction found",
   "message"=>"Something went wrong, please contact support!",
   "mode"=>"test",
   "timestamp"=>"2017-11-24T08:07:40Z",
   "descriptor"=>"rwgwg",
   "sent_to_acquirer"=>"false"}}
```

How I can get the keys from this structure?

Comment: `response_data.keys` for keys; `response_data.values` for values. Why does your title say "values" but you ask about "keys"? :) You'll find questions are more precise the more precise your question is.

Answer (score 2):

```
response_data.keys + response_data.values.flat_map(&:keys)
```

Comment: One additional question how I can get the code value(in this case 410)?

Comment: Please don't ask questions in comments. And avoid changing or adding questions. Ask in another thread.